# pass data to multiple textbox with 1 form vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have issue with passing data in VB.NET and I'm new in **vb.net + mysql**. I don't know is it possible or not. I have some TextBoxes and I want fill those with userID or something. I want to make this like a modal on php.

When I clik TextBox, 1 form shows up with ComboBox and submit button to pass data to TextBox on previous Form. I've done it with 1 TextBox, but I can't pass it to other TextBox. Here is my code:

Form1.vb

```vb
Private Sub TextBox4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.Click
    'This is method **in my logic** can throw back data to TextBox4 from Form2.vb'
    Form2.Label1.Text = TextBox4.Name
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Form2.vb

```vb
Private Sub AddTeam_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call getUSers()
End Sub
Sub getUSers()
    Call connection()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE status='Active'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(str, conn)
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If rd.HasRows Then
        Do While rd.Read
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(rd("id"))
        Loop
    Else

    End If
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim nik = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    'Here is the issue, if i pass to 1 TextBox (like TextBox4 as sample) it`s easy, but if pass to another TextBox i have no idea to do that'
    Form1.TextBox4.Text = nik
    Me.Refresh()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

*note: I know there are many ways to do so, like change TextBox to ComboBox and fill with data, but I want this method*

I'm sorry for my poor logic in vb.net. I was better with PHP before.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Now that you have Option Strict ON you will see that nik cannot be assigned to a `.Text` property because it is an Object not a String. `Dim nik = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString` should fix that problem.

Comment: To pass `nik` just add another line. `Form1.TextBox2.Text = nik` You can get rid of the  `Me.Refresh()`. It does nothing here.

Comment: Call is no longer needed in vb.net. Me.Close does not require the Me. I know your code is using the connection improperly. Connection objects should be in the same method as your code. Connections need to be closed and disposed.

Comment: Thanks @Mary i will try your suggestions. and i will update here what i get.

Comment: hi @Mary, i think i will use another method. thanks for your reply, i appreciated it